# Exposing data object through a service?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, webservice-client

I created a SOAP service that is supposed to return a Category object and a CategoryCollection through a SubSonic query.  The problem is that I can return a DataTable of data just fine, however the objects returned from the service are of active record type, internally, and not of my DAL entities.

For example when I consume the service, I see SOAPService.Category, but not SOAPService.CategoryCollection (I should be able to see SOAPService.[all other data entities], and the SOAPService.Category is of active record type, and doesn't contain the actual Category properties.

Both classes defined through my SubSonic DAL generation.

```
 namespace TrainingWebService.DAL
 {
     /// <summary>
 // Strongly-typed collection for the Category class.
     /// </summary>
     [Serializable]
     public partial class CategoryCollection : ActiveList<Category, CategoryCollection>
     {  
     .
     .   
     .
```

and

```
/// <summary>
/// This is an ActiveRecord class which wraps the Categories table.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public partial class Category : ActiveRecord<Category>, IActiveRecord
{
.
.
.
```

These classes exist in the TrainingWebService solution.

TrainingWebService.ISOAPService.cs:

using VRPCTrainingWebService.DAL;

> namespace TrainingWebService {
>       // VRPC Training Web Service - Interface
>       [ServiceContract]
>       public interface ISOAPService
>       {
>
> ```
>     [OperationContract]
>     string GetDBConnectionStringDetails();
>
>     [OperationContract]
>     string ReturnSameString(string someString);
>
>
>     //
>     // Database-related
>     //
>
>     [OperationContract]                             // categories
>     CategoryCollection GetAllCategories();          // SubSonic object
>
>     [OperationContract]
>     DataTable GetAllCategoriesAsDataTable();
>
>     [OperationContract]
>     DataTable GetCategoryAsDataTable(int id);
>
>     [OperationContract]                             
>     Category GetCategoryByID(int id);               // SubSonic object 
>
>     [OperationContract]   
>     // products
>     ProductCollection GetAllProducts();
>
>     [OperationContract]
>     Product GetProductByID(int id);
>
>     [OperationContract]                             // suppliers
>     SupplierCollection GetAllSuppliers();
>
>     [OperationContract]
>     Supplier GetSupplierByID(int id);
>
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

In my SOAPService.cs

```
 public CategoryCollection GetAllCategories()            // get a collection of all categories
    {
        return DataCaller.GetAllCategories();
    }

    public DataTable GetAllCategoriesAsDataTable()
    {
        return DataCaller.GetCategoriesAsDataTable();
    }

    public DataTable GetCategoryAsDataTable(int id)
    {
        return DataCaller.GetCategoryAsDataTable(id);
    }


Here's a snip of the DataCaller code.

       /// <summary>
        /// Get all categories - returns a collection of categories
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static CategoryCollection GetAllCategories()
        {
            categoryCollection =
                DB.Select().From("Categories")
                    .ExecuteAsCollection<CategoryCollection>();

            return categoryCollection;
        }


        public static DataTable GetCategoryAsDataTable(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                dtResults = new Select()
                                .Where(Category.Columns.CategoryID).IsEqualTo(id)
                                .From(Category.Schema)
                                .ExecuteAsCollection<CategoryCollection>().ToDataTable();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return dtResults;
        }
```

I think the problem may be in exposing the *.DAL entities through my web service, so they are accessible.

I have this working just fine in another solution I built a while back, but for some reason I can't see what I'm missing here.

Comment: Perhaps a DataContract would be applicable?

Comment: Ah yes!  I was using an old version of my DAL generator that was missing the CollectionDataContract and DataContract additions.

Comment: Yeah, silly me.  Looking that was exactly it.  I also noticed I had an old version on Codeplex (http://subsonic23tvp.codeplex.com/) that didn't support the CollectionDataContract and DataContracts - now updated.  Can't mark your comment as answer though.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer, though it's such a short one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to decorate your DAL entites with [DataContract], if applicable.

[DataContractAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)

Comment: Also added CollectionDataContract and Serializable attributes.